# Find probability density function for random variable of fair coin toss

Tags: real-analysis, probability, density-function

Consider a fair coin. Let $X:\{H,T\}\to \Bbb R$ be a random variable with $X(H)=-1$ and $X(T)=1$.

1. Find the PDF of X $$P\{X\le t\} $$
2. Flipping the coin 4 times and associate with the sequence of iid {Xn} where Xn are defined as above. Compute $$P\{\frac{X_1+...+X_4}{2}\le t\} $$

I am able to find $E(X)=0$ and $var(X)=1$. But I am not sure how to find the probability density function $f(x)$ for $P\{X\le t\}$, where $P\{X\le t\}=\int_\infty^tf(x)dx$. Since X can only have two values, do I need to discuss different values for t?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: $\Pr(X\le t)$ gives the *cumulative distribution function* (cdf) of $X$. Is that what you want? Or do you want the probability distribution function of $X$? For the cdf, you will have to consider different ranges of values for $t$.

Comment: The professor said it should be pdf instead of cdf.

Comment: @Leila No, pdf means "probability density function" and discrete random variables do not have one.  Rather, they have a "probability mass function" or pmf.  In any case, $\mathsf P(X\leq y)$ *is* a "cumulative distribution function" or CDF.

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is a discrete random variable, with support of $\{-1,1\}$ and a *probability mass function* (pmf) of $\mathsf p_X(x)~=~\tfrac 1 2~\mathbf 1_{x\in\{-1;1\}}$ , then the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) will be a piecewise function.   Also since this is a discrete random variable, we sum rather than integrate as we would for a continuous random variable.

$$F_X(t) ~=~ \sum_{\substack{x\in \{-1,1\}\\x\leq t}} \mathsf p_X(x)$$

The value will be zero for $t$ less than $-1$, and one for $t$ of at least $1$ , but what will it be for $t$ in the intervening interval?

$$F_X(t)~=~\begin{cases}0 & : t<-1\\ ? & : -1\leq t< 1\\1 & : 1\leq t\end{cases}$$

$\Box$